# Classes of convex functions

Tags: functions

Can someone please explain what means class of function? More precisely, how do we define relation for which we have classes of convex, quasiconvex etc. functions?

Answer (score 0):

Classes are generalizations of sets. Often when you study some kind of object (for example just sets) and you want to consider all of them together they do not form a set again. Therefore one takes objects that allow to speak of "the set of all sets" etc. and they are called classes. The class of all convex functions is just the collection of all convex functions etc.